# Cannot install Windows 10 Technical Preview as a virtual machine in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-8.1

Using latest VB in Xubuntu 14.04.

When selecting "other Windows" the installation was stuck at the first step with a black screen, but following instruction on the web I find that the proper option is 8.1.

[image]

Selecting that, the installation starts only to end up with no drive visible

[image]

What else?

:)

---

EDIT-- OTHER SETTINGS

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You told us nothing about your virtual machine's configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound - what details should I report?

Comment: To start with, what type of storage have you selected for this VM?

Comment: @Ramhound -updated

Comment: There is a work around.  Install any Windows then install Windows 10 over it while within Windows.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - updated

Comment: From that screenshot, it looks like you haven't defined a virtual HDD at all, which would explain why the installer doesn't have anywhere to install to.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - that error comes from trying a workaround... that should be the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a virtual HDD. Windows can't install if there's nothing to install to.